# Where can I ask questions about software industry vocabulary?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Are there sites where it is on-topic to ask about the proper usage, and tips to avoid overuse of *citizen developer*, a term found in a sponsored blog article<sup>1</sup>?

*Citizen developer* looks to me as a buzzword. Buzzwords are not bad *per se*, but they might be annoying, especially when using a lot of them or when they are overused.

---

Reading a recent sponsored blog post<sup>1</sup> I found a term that was new to me, *citizen developer*. It made me remember terms that I learned several years ago like *civic hacking*, *civic tech* among others. Googling about this new term for me I found a Wikipedia article in German<sup>2</sup> about this term having only one link to another language, Polish. The apparently most relevant search results about this term in English come from companies selling stuff like analysis reports and courses about [low-code development platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-code_development_platform)/[no-code development platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-code_development_platform) software development <sup>3, 4</sup>.

The search [*"citizen developer"* in Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%22citizen%20developer%22) returns six results, one from Super User, and the rest from Stack Overflow.

From the Super User result (it's an answer)

> The low-code/citizen developer approach would be just to hit the Expand button in the column header for your Data column.

From Stack Overflow results (5 questions, all of them have 0 score, only one of them have an answer, it was self-answered)

1. > Citizen Developer here trying to figure this out.
2. > [Warning: I am a citizen developer and not a professional - apologizing in advance]
3. > [Citizen Developer Alert] ...
4. > I am a K2 'citizen developer' and my company uses the cloud-based version which does not allow for 3rd party bolt-ons.

Per SO guidelines, the mention of the statement using "citizen developer" in the posts having them should be removed as they look to be "chit-chat".

1. > We have a Citizen Developer RPA currently running and we are trying to improve it.

From the featured snippet from searching [Citizen Developer RPA](https://www.google.com/search?q=citizen%20developer%20rpa):

> The UiPath RPA Citizen Developer training is a learning plan that teaches you how to become a citizen developer. It combines a range of our courses on UiPath StudioX, and how to use it to create a variety of automations.

It might have some sense as an SO question but not for considering SO as a site to ask about the meaning and proper usage of *citizen developer*.

Searching [buzzword](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=buzzword) returned 2,876 results.

The most relevant results:

1. [Dealing with "buzzword creep"](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/17178/75233) from Workplace
2. [Weeding out real agile from buzzword agile in an interview](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/36925/233431) (closed) from Software Engineering
3. [Why are overused buzzwords like Cyber and Hacking still prevalent in our industry?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/131676/151990) (closed) from Information Security
4. [Is “Click bait” an Internet buzzword? How can I rephrase it?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/210357/355513) from English Language & Usage
5. [Is rapport a cognitive phenomenon?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/7642) from [Psychology & Neuroscience](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/tour)
6. https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/5505/38805 from [Physical Fitness](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/tour)
7. https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/5503/25847 from [Project Management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/tour)
8. https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/49698/46658 from [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tour)

---

Looking at the above questions it looks that the most appropriate sites to make a question about the meaning and usage of *citizen developer* might be

- [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/tour)
- [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour)

Is this correct or I'm overseeing something?

Notes:

1. [Speeding software innovation with low-code/no-code tools](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/11/15/speeding-software-innovation-with-low-code-no-code-tools/)
2. [Citizen Developer | Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizen_Developer)
3. [Citizen Developer | PMI](https://www.pmi.org/citizen-developer)
4. [Citizen Developer | Gartner](https://www.gartner.com/en/information-technology/glossary/citizen-developer)

---

Continued searching efforts:

Related terms "shadow IT":

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/874242/1595451 from Stack Overflow (looks to be off-topic in SO)
- [Forbidding or controlling "Hidden IT..." Who should write and maintain ad-hoc software applications?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/174789/233431) from Software Engineering
- [How do I convince my boss of the value of using more modern tools?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/72515/75233) (closed) from Workplace

Answer (score 3):

After posting the the question I continue researching and found that Project Management has [`\[definition]`](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition)

> For questions about the definitions of project management related terms.

I also found that the Project Managment Institute (PMI) have published the book "Citizen Development: The Handbook for Creators and Change Makers", and PM has also a tag for this organization, [`[pmi]`](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pmi), so I posted the following question there

- [Is "citizen development" <software development> an old thing with new name in the project management field?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/34497/25847)
  [`[definition]`](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/definition) [`[pmi]`](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pmi)